An exact sequence in group cohomology
Let $H$ and $G$ be finite groups. Let $A$ be an abelian group with a $G$ action, and write $A^G$ for the abelian group of fixed points. Is there an exact sequence of the following shape:
$$0\rightarrow H^1(G;Hom(H,A))\rightarrow H^2(H;A^G)\rightarrow H^2(H;A)?$$ Possibly, it also becomes right exact if the right hand-side is replaced by $H^2(H;A)^G$?
